# In the Double Slit Experiment, what type of wave are we talking about?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, double-slit-experiment

I was learning about the double slit experiment and simple explanation is that there is wave interference. Although I do not quite understand the wave bit. We know that light is a wave.
[image: This Sine type wave]

But in the image of the wave interference we see something like two ripples (in water) that interfere.
[image: Wave interference]

I couldn't understand that how could a sine wave, pass through a slit and then suddenly become ripples.

P.S.
If we imagine a sine wave passing through a slit, we (or probably I) should expect a sine wave, because the front side of the sine wave is one-dimensional and that passing through a slit just a wee wide, shouldn't change anything.

Comment: Are you asking how the light is able to spread out as it exits the slit?

Comment: The lines you see represent the maxima of the sine probability waves.

Comment: @Shubhkarman Sandhu those curves escaping the slit represent the wavefront not the sine wave itself.

Comment: The cross-section of a series of ripples is a sine wave. This is true whether the cross-section is longitudinal or radial and the ripples are in light, water or anything else.

Comment: The probability of finding the photon at a place when measuring is related to the (operator-)weighted inner product of the photon's wave function, which is a complex number at each position, with dynamics as the Schrödinger equation tells. I don't know if the first picture is supposed to show the wave function or the electric field.

Answer (score 2):

As the wave passes through both slits the light diffracts into two coherent waves. Try to imagine the sine wave graphic (top picture) but from above. It's the same principle as a ripple; it's just crests and troughs. The lower graphic can be misleading as when you'd do this experiment with a laser there isn't nearly that much spread of the beam before it encounters the slits.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction

[image]